# Return of Datetime value

Tags: apex, datetime, timezone

I am new to Apex.

I have instantiated the Datetime field with (2019, 12, 31, 12, 12, 12) where hour/minute/sec all are '12'. but in the output it is returning '20:12:12'.

Please help me to understand the cause. Screenshot attached.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You are witnessing the automating conversion of a GMT time (the numbers you passed in to `DateTime.newInstance`) to your local timezone. The mechanism helps when orgs have users working in multiple timezones

See the various [Datetime Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm) methods that output with and without this conversion.